# Prevent form from submitting until validation

Tags: javascript, html

I am making form and I have some problems validating it.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="regForm" class="form-group" method="POST" action="signup.php">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2>Job Pocket</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input placeholder="email" class="form-control"type="text" name="email" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input placeholder="password"  class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="pass">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input placeholder="confirm password"  class="form-control" type="password" name="confirmpass" id="confirmpass">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input placeholder="first name"  class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input placeholder="last name"  class="form-control" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="submit"  value="submit" name="submitsignup" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  </div>
  <hr>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#regForm").submit(function(event){
        if(document.getElementById("email")=="" || document.getElementById("password") || document.getElementById("last_name") || document.getElementById("first_name"))
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Even with this javascript code added the form still submits to signup.php.
And should I add extre checks in php aswell.

Comment: `HTMLElement`s are *truthy*, so `|| document.getElementById("password") ` etc will always evaluate to `true`. You need to access their `.value` to get their value. Why not just use `required`?

Comment: Done, but it still submits. whats the better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//add return function on it

```
<form id="regForm" class="form-group" method="POST" action="signup.php">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <h2>Job Pocket</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input placeholder="email" class="form-control"type="text" name="email" id="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input placeholder="password"  class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="pass">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input placeholder="confirm password"  class="form-control" type="password" name="confirmpass" id="confirmpass">
                            </div>
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input placeholder="first name"  class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input placeholder="last name"  class="form-control" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="button"  onclick="return validation()" value="submit" name="submitsignup" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                        </form>




<script>
public  function validation(){
  if(document.getElementById("email").value=="" || document.getElementById("password").value="" || document.getElementById("last_name").value="" || document.getElementById("first_name")).value==""{
        return false; }
else {
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
}
}
</script>
```

or use this

//add required on input it will automatically return message

```
<form id="regForm" class="form-group" method="POST" action="signup.php">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <h2>Job Pocket</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input placeholder="email" class="form-control"type="text" name="email" id="email" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input placeholder="password"  class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="pass" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input placeholder="confirm password"  class="form-control" type="password" name="confirmpass" id="confirmpass" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input placeholder="first name"  class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input placeholder="last name"  class="form-control" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="submit"   value="submit" name="submitsignup" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Thanks alot it worked, how can I display a message to inform the user?

Comment: try the second code  with  required it returns message itself

Comment: That great what if i want to check the format of the input ?

Comment: what do you mean by format ?     do you want to check if its integer or text ?

Comment: Like if the user has entered a valid email address

Comment: you should connect to mail server (over SMTP )

Comment: I am getting this error document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function.  Due to this document.getElementById("regForm").submit();

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this

```
if(document.getElementById("email")=="" || document.getElementById("password")=="" || document.getElementById("last_name")=="" || document.getElementById("first_name")=="")
```

Comment: Done. But it still submits

Comment: whats the better way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `.value` to check the values of inputs. Also, you have to use `preventDefault` in submit function to prevent form submission:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#regForm").submit(function(event){
    if(document.getElementById("email").value == "" || document.getElementById("password").value == "" || document.getElementById("last_name").value == "" || document.getElementById("first_name").value == "")
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Since you're using jquery, you can also use its selector:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#regForm").submit(function(event){
    if($("#email").val() == "" || $("#password").val() == "" || $("#last_name").val() == "" || $("#first_name").val() == "")
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: It still submits

Comment: whats the better way of doing it?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should only add "required" in the html tag in  tags. It'll automatically add display text that the field is required.
Like this:

```
<input placeholder="last name"  class="form-control" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" required>
```

Comment: How will I check if the user has entered the right format?

Comment: You can use either the "pattern" attribute if you're willing to use regular expressions. Otherwise javascript can also be used to validate the inputs. Check patterns from here: http://html5pattern.com/ . In tag it'll be like:                                 <input placeholder="password (7 or more characters)"  class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="pass" required pattern=".{7,}">

Comment: Take a look at the documentation on the HTML Form validation: [Form data validation | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation)

Answer (score 0):

what about using event.preventDefault() like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#regForm").submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
        if(document.getElementById("email")=="" || document.getElementById("password")=="" || document.getElementById("last_name")=="" || document.getElementById("first_name")=="")
        return false;
    });
</script>
```